# Where to start by creating this effect

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine, android-animation

I am developing application and I need to create animation like in Android Chrome when opening more tabs. It is drag and drop effects or something else, just give me the clue where to start building this effect.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html) example should tell you something it's explaining about OpenGl

Answer (score 0):

You should start reading about OpenGL library [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).